# Macbook pro trackpad stops working after plugging in USB mouse in Windows 7 under bootcamp

Tags: macbook-pro, bootcamp, trackpad, windows

We have a new Macbook Pro which we've installed Windows 7 under boot camp. We've also installed the drivers off the OSX CD.

When I plugged in a USB mouse the Trackpad stops working, which is fine because I've got the mouse. When I unplug the USB mouse the track pad still doesn't work.

Has anyone else experienced the behaviour? Is there a solution to it?

Comment: You might try looking under the Windows preferences to see if there's a setting that automatically disables the trackpad when a mouse is plugged in.

Comment: I am experiencing the same problem! I connect my USB Mouse and the trackpad won't work anymore, neither the options for trackpad appear on Boot Camp software for windows 7.

Answer (score -1):

During boot camp assistant partitioning, it prompted you to create  windows support folder. After installing windows you should have run setup from this folder. If you run it again and reboot, you should have your track-pad driver restored. When you run it again, select repair.

Comment: -1: generic answer that just points to standard procedures; doesn't seem any research was done on this

Comment: I wrote this while I was walking through this issue on my macbook. It helped me.

Comment: Perhaps, however in no way is it related to the problem OP is experiencing.  How someone chooses to run Windows Setup has nothing to do with a trackpad being disabled when a mouse is plugged in.

Comment: @PatrickMcMahon Actually it does, since he specifically mentioned *using bootcamp.* The steps I have outlined have resolved the issue on actual hardware for identical symptoms

Comment: Doubtful.  OP says the trackpad works until he plugs in an external USB mouse.  This is a simple Control Panel setting.  It is not a drivers issue.